# Java 2D Game Memory Leak

Tags: java

This is the first time i'm using stackoverflow and hoping to get some help understanding an issue I'm running into. I've been working on a little 2D tile game for a a few months now as time permits, but I think I've run into a memory leak on drawing the graphics or at least somewhere around that part of the code. Everything works fine, the game runs and all images render, etc but last night I decided to see how the cpu and memory was holding up when running the program. I noticed that the memory just keeps growing and growing as time goes on. Over 10 - 15 minutes can grow up to 150mb from starting around 50mb. I commented out a section of code where the graphics is drawn and a timer's action performed fires off. I think the culprit is somewhere around there as I don't see the memory growing unnecessarily when commenting that out.

In the class where the graphics is drawn I create and store a buffered image which is around 864x768 and made up using a variety of smaller images 32x32.

I use a javax.swing.Timer that fires off every so often and in the action performed method I just run a method update() which checks for player input and then gets a subimage of the big buffered image via the buffered image subimage method and displays that to the canvas.

I'm thinking this may have something to do with the timer but not for sure.

Here's some of the code:

```
    private BufferedImage map;
    private Timer timer;            
    private BufferStrategy bs;
    private Graphics g;
    private boolean isInitialized; 

    public class World extends Canvas implements ActionListener {

        public World() {
            isInitialized = false;
            timer = new Timer(25, this);
            timer.setInitialDelay(100);
            timer.start();
        }   

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!isInitialized) {
                createBufferStrategy(3);
                bs = getBufferStrategy();
                isInitialied = true;
            }
            update();
        }

        public void update() {
            player.input();
            g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            BufferedImage temp = map.getSubimage(x, 
                y, viewWidth, viewHeight);
            g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(player, playerX, playerY,
                null);
            bs.show();
            g.dispose();
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

Okay, so after taking some time to research Garbage Collection, JVM, etc I found that I didn't understand how those things work on a fundamental level. I profiled the project and found GC working as expected, etc. So all in all what I thought to be a memory leak turns out not necessarily the case. What I based my concern on initially was that from windows task manager I saw the memory growing and never stabilizing for the process to which I just knew that couldn't be right from the code, second checking, trying different code, etc. I feel a lot better knowing what I know now!

Also, I adopted the method:

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2,
    int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, ImageObserver observer)
```

in place of:
    BufferedImage temp = map.getSubimage(x, y, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, null);

Now there's a different issue that I've run into. On my desktop I use for programming and testing the game, everything is running fine and works as I'd like when I just test the game with no apps in the background. However, when I spin up a browser and try watch something on youtube or netflix and then test run the game, there's a milisecond pause (anywhere from 25 - 50ms). This pause happens every second which is noticeable and definitely not desired! I ran some tests and it happens only during this draw method:

public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2,
        int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, ImageObserver observer)

But again only in that specific scenario, and even in that scenario it completes  within 1-2 ms each time, except after a second or close to it, there's a delay.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is not a memory leak. This is how Swing classes and JVM works.

Comment: Have you taken a heap dump and looked for any anomalies there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere that you're flushing the `BufferedImage` so it will be holding onto all the memory it has previously allocated.

Once you're done with the `BufferedImage temp` value, it needs to be flushed with `temp.flush()`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get a sub image in order to draw it into the `Graphics`.

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,
                int dx1,
                int dy1,
                int dx2,
                int dy2,
                int sx1,
                int sy1,
                int sx2,
                int sy2,
                ImageObserver observer)
```

[This overload of `drawImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) allows you to specify the portion of the source image to draw directly: the `s` in `sx1`, `sy1` etc parameters means "source".